# Compiler flag "-Wshadow" doesn't work in CodeBloks

Tags: c, gcc, codeblocks, gcc-warning

I realized that I need compiler flag `-Wshadow` after I mess up some code, so I decide to use it in `Codeblocks` too, but it doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

The following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int i = 0;
    int arr[] = {1,2,3};

    for (int i=0 ; i < 3 ; i++){
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }

    printf("\nI = %d\n",i);
}
```

If I try to compile it in my `Terminal` with the following `flags` :

```
-Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wstrict-prototypes -Wconversion -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Wshadow -O0 -g
```

I get the following Output, which is OK:

```
program.c: In function ‘main’:
program.c:7:14: error: declaration of ‘i’ shadows a previous local [-Werror=shadow]
     for (int i=0 ; i < 3 ; i++){
              ^
program.c:4:9: note: shadowed declaration is here
     int i = 0;
         ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Now using the same Compiler `Flags` doesn't seems to work, compiles fine with no warnings, just like the flag `-Wshadow` is not present.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

GCC version is:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 5.3.0-3ubuntu1~14.04) 5.3.0 20151204
```

Comment: Look at the "Build Log" tab in Code::Blocks , it will show the exact commandline being sent to the compiler. Check that this commandline has your flag in it; and use copy-paste to try the same commandline in your console . Any warnings would also appear in Build Log.

Comment: [This](http://pastebin.com/raw/mrfuTFgj) is my Build-Log

Comment: Nothing is being built there, you just ran the program you build previously.  In the Build menu click "Rebuild"

Comment: All other Flags are Working Fine, but `-Wshadow` don't

Comment: @M.M You right, I had to [rebuild](http://pastebin.com/raw/9BkvDte9) it. Thank you. If you post an Asnwer with this Typo I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add compiler flags via the IDE, it doesn't automatically mark any existing object files or executable as out-of-date.

You need to click on "Rebuild" to do a full rebuild of your code using the new flags.